Is it possible for Vite to create manifest.json (or file) with own object content?
Is there a way to create manifest.json or other json file by Vite on build that will contain my own object with also path to index js and css with hash? For example:
{ jsScript: 'path/to/script/[name][hash].js', anotherKey: 'myOwnValue' }
I was looking in vite docs and rollupjs but couldn't find solution there.
Also tried vite-plugin-generate-file plugin but couldn't pass hash.

You can use closeBundle Rollup's hook to modify the manifest:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import fs from 'fs';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        {
            name: 'postbuild-commands',
            closeBundle: () => {
                const path = './dist/.vite/manifest.json';
                const manifest = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path).toString());
                manifest['index.html'].customProp = true;
                fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2));
            }
        },
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    build: {
        manifest: true
    }
})


